Using Wayland and KDE for dual-monitor switching with custom key bindings
A little bit of background: I have this 8bitdo keyboard that comes with two extra buttons. I also have two monitors and want to use these to switch between "left", "right" and "both". I'm using KDE.
One of the keys simulates Ctrl+Meta+Alt+Z, which is bound to switching to left screen in KDE, the other is Ctrl+Meta+Shift+Z, bound to right. Now switching to "both" is the tricky part. Under X, I wrote myself a quick console Qt app querying keyboard modifier keys, which would look for Ctrl+Meta, then for either Alt (switch to left), Shift (switch to right) or if both modifiers were present within 0.3s, it would switch to both screens.
Unfortunately this does not seem to work under Wayland, with Qt's QGuiApplication::queryKeyboardModifiers() returning no modifier at all times. I guess this is due to how wayland works.
Do you know if there is some sort of functionality in KDE, or something I could do in wayland, to get the desired functionality? I guess libinput would work too, I have https://github.com/oblitum/Interception running in my setup.
